# extracting a word starting with a specific letter from a string in php

Tags: php, string

I need to search a word exact same character or similar character  not in middle of the word or any other character in a word.
   The program is in php.
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need you to post your attempt so far. Thanks

Comment: if i search a word starts with coc it will display couchey,cochin I don't want that i need exact word starts with cochin

Comment: Do you need to retrieve the position of the word in the sentence? Or extract the actual word that begins with $needle? And what do you mean by "similar"?

Comment: I need actual word that begins with search letters otherwise get similar word not in middle of the word

Comment: See solution for absolute matches below. If you want *fuzzy search*, that's a lot more complex and you'd need to clarify a lot more what exactly you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to demonstrate a non-regexp solution for absolute matches:

```
$needle = 'coc';
$sentence = 'I loves me some cochin, really.';

$matches = array_filter(str_word_count($sentence,1),
                        function($item) use ($needle) {
                            return (substr($item,0,strlen($needle) == $needle));
                        }
                       );
```

**EDIT**

Explanation:

The [str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) function with a second argument of 1 or 2 returns an array of all the words that are in $string. It's better than exploding on a space, because it takes other punctuation marks (such as the comma after "cochin") into account as well.

That array of words is then fed to the [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function, together with a filter callback (defined as a lambda or anonymous function). The lambda returns a true or false for each entry ($item) in the array argument: if true than that entry is included in $matches; if false, then it isn't.

The defined lambda function is passed each $item (array entry) in turn, and also the $needle (by way of the "use" clause). It simply compares the first characters of the $item value with the needle, and returns a true or false depending on the match. Note that it's a case-sensitive comparison. if you wanted case-insensitive you'd want to use strtoupper() or strtolower() against both the substr() value and the $needle value before the comparison.

If you wanted a "similar" match, then you could replace the comparison in the lambda function with a comparison of the [levenshtein()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) or [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) values of $item and $needle, with a %age similarity (or possibly the [metaphone()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) function) to identify whether they should be considered similar or not.

```
$needle = 'coc';
$sentence = 'I loves me some cochin, really; and "couchey" is pretty cool too';

$matches = array_filter(str_word_count($sentence,1),
                        function($item) use ($needle) {
                            return (levenshtein($item,$needle,1,1,0) == 0);
                        }
                       );
```

Comment: i need the explanation for this.I think this may be helpful,i accept it but need explanation

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression you're looking for is `\b(NEEDLE\w+)`. Like so:

```
$needle = 'coc';
$sentence = 'I loves me some cochin, really.';

if (preg_match('/\b(' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . '\w+)/', $sentence, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
}
```

Comment: it's not helpful i need somewhat similar words not too many different word thanks for your response

Comment: sorry that i could not entirely serve your needs based on your vague one run on sentence description of your problem

Comment: thanks for your advance i am trying to develop the sentence formation